# PHP, MYSQL - Ошибка expects at least ... parameters (Помогите пожалуйста)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

**Только начал изучать php. Создаю чат.**

**Выдает ошибку:**

*Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat\includes\functions\chat.func.php on line 7
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat\includes\functions\chat.func.php on line 11*

**В чем может быть дело?**

**Вот код:**

```
<?php

function get_msg() {

$query = "SELECT 'Sender', 'Message', FROM 'chat'.'chat'";

$run = mysqli_query($query);

$messages = array();

while($message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $messages[] = array('sender' =>$message['Sender'], 'message'=>$message['Message']);
}

return $messages;
}

function send_msg($sender, $message) {

if(!empty($sender) && !empty($message)) {

    $sender = mysqli_real_escape_string($sender);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($message);

    $query = "INSERT INTO 'chat'.'chat' VALUES (null, '{$sender}', '$message')";

    if($run = mysqli_query($query)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Вы пробовали перевести сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде чем писать на различные ресурсы "Спасите помогите!" необходимо **ВСЕГДА, АБСОЛЮТНО ВСЕГДА И БЕЗ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЙ** перевести сообщение об ошибке. И оно вам скажет, что не так. Перевод вашей ошибки:

> Предупреждение: mysqli_query () ожидает как минимум 2 параметра, 1 задан

Смотрим в ваш код `mysqli_query($query)` и правда 1 параметр, а нужно два. Что же не так? Смотрим в **[документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)**:

> Процедурный стиль
>
> `mysqli_query(mysqli $link, string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ])`
>
> **link** -
>   Только для процедурного стиля: Идентификатор соединения, полученный с помощью **mysqli_connect()** или **mysqli_init()**

Соответственно что? Правильно: у вас не передан этот самый идентификатор подключения.

Аналогично с `mysqli_fetch_assoc`...

Comment: @AntonKolesnik Таки а документация-то на что?)) Переводишь ошибку, видишь что не так с каким методом или конструкцией - смотришь в доки, что ты сделал не так. Если всё сделано так, как описано в доках, а у тебя все равно ошибки - тогда пора кого-то и спросить. А так....вы доки вообще не открываете, да?

Comment: @AntonKolesnik должно выглядеть так `$run = mysqli_query($link, $query);` ..... где `$link` является результатом подключения `$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");` ...... то есть в твоём случае единственный вариант (рабочий но плохой) - это использовать её как глобальную переменную `function get_msg() { global $link; $query = "SELECT 'Sender', 'Message', FROM 'chat'.'chat'";

$run = mysqli_query($link, $query);` ...........